# Wordpress post_type make post_title required before inserting/updating post

Tags: wordpress

I try to make the default "title" field from a custom post type in wordpress as a required field before insert or updating a post.

Whats the best way to do that without third plugins?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some custom validation code.

More information: [Wordpress validation for title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514871/wordpress-validation-for-title)

I have make some other changes in code. I have used jquery validation. please put below code in you function.php file

```
    /** ADD Validation for title */
function force_post_title_init()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function force_post_title()
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "
        jQuery('#publish').click(function(){
              var testervar = jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]')
              .find('#title');
              if (testervar.val().length < 1)
              {
                  jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]').css('border', '1px solid red');
                  $( '#titlewrap' ).after('<label>Post title is required</label>'); // Make it red according your requirement 
                  return false;
              }
          });
        ";
    echo "</script>\n";
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_post_title_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_title');
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_post_title');
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the post is insert and a new row is added in the db (as draft). Wel i see the notice box, but In this case the post_title field is not required.

Comment: maybe something that i dont understand but i can't find any solution to validate post_title and post_comment before the post is insert into the database... help please !

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggested improvements to the code:

```
<?php
function force_post_title() {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ( 'book' == $post_type ) {
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery('form#post').submit(function () {
                 let titleDiv = jQuery('#titlediv').find('#title');
                 if (titleDiv.val().length < 1) {
                     titleDiv.css('border', '1px solid red');
                     jQuery('#titlewrap').after('<label style="color: red;">Book title is required</label>'); // Make it red according your requirement
                     return false;
                 }
             });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_title');
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_post_title');
```